# When to remove the pendrive after installing Ubuntu?

Tags: installation, usb-drive

I don't exactly know when to remove the USB used for installing Ubuntu. If I don't remove it even when the option 'restart now' comes after installation, I go to the same option of try Ubuntu, install Ubuntu... If I try removing it before clicking restart now, I get a screen with error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the install is complete, shut down the machine.  Remove the USB device then power up the machine.

Answer (score 0):

It is because your machine is set to boot from usb first and hard drive in 2nd or 3rd place. You can either change the boot order to boot from hard drive first in bios setting or just remove the USB after finishing installation and reboot again.

You can invoke bios setting by pressing `F12` or `F8` etc.(depends on hardware) just after powering on your machine.

Best of luck.